# 301 Redirect Tumblr Pages

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, http-status-code-301

I am migrating my old blog posts on a tumblr account to my own CMS and I'm in the process of 301 redirecting my posts in my .htaccess file, but I'm unsure of the proper way to do that with two subfolders.

Here is my current thought process:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on

Redirect 301 /post/101421063804/how-to-fix-paypal-referral-revenue-issues http://personalsite.com/blog/how-to-fix-paypal-referral-revenue-issues

Redirect 301 /post/96013172504/basic-seo-checklist http://personalsite.com/blog/basic-seo-checklist
```

Is this the correct way to lay out my .htaccess file?

Comment: What problems did you encountered? Why do you doubt of the functionality of that code? You can test your code by [checking the headers](https://www.google.ro/search?q=check%20headers%20online) of those specific urls.

Comment: I ran a test and I receive `Cannot GET /post/101421063804/how-to-fix-paypal-referral-revenue-issues`